# Load icon from .DLL in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, windows, wxwidgets

I am attempting to load a wxIcon in Windows by loading from a system DLL (as the mime system told me that the icon for such a file type was in the DLL), eg.

```
wxIcon icon;
icon.LoadFile("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\zipfldr.dll", wxICON_DEFAULT_TYPE);
```

This fails but I was wondering if there was any way in the codebase of loading this, other than resorting to native Win32 functions.

Also, if there are native Win32 functions, does anyone know what they are?

EDIT: I have tried the following with no success:

```
::wxInitAllImageHandlers();
wxMimeTypesManager manager;
wxFileType* type = manager.GetFileTypeFromExtension("sys");
wxIconLocation location;
if (type->GetIcon(&location))
{
  // location is something like C:\WINDOWS\system32\imageres.dll
  wxIcon icon;
  if (!icon.LoadFile(location.GetFileName(), wxBITMAP_TYPE_ICON /*I have tried wxICON_DEFAULT_TYPE too*/))
  {
    // Failed!
  }
}
```

EDIT 2: In response to VZ, I have tried the following with no success sadly:

```
::wxInitAllImageHandlers();
wxMimeTypesManager manager;
wxFileType* type = manager.GetFileTypeFromExtension("sys");
wxIconLocation location;
if (type->GetIcon(&location))
{
  // location is something like C:\WINDOWS\system32\imageres.dll,
  //with an appropriate index as retrieved by location.GetIndex(), which is -67.
  wxIcon icon(location);
  if (!icon.IsOk())
  {
    BREAK;
    // Failed!
  }
}
```

EDIT 3:
Thanks for everyone's help - works fine if I use `wxBITMAP_TYPE_ICO` instead of `wxBITMAP_TYPE_ICON` (notice the *N*), and also I was putting my test code in my app's constructor instead of in `::OnInit`. It worked in `OnInit` but not in the constructor so that's a lesson learned!
Thanks everyone for the help and speedy responses, much appreciated as always.

Comment: The second set of code you posted is working for me. Although according to the documentation for wxMimeTypesManager, "The application should not construct its own manager: it should use the object pointer wxTheMimeTypesManager", so the second line should probably be removed and the third line should be `wxFileType* type = ::wxTheMimeTypesManager->GetFileTypeFromExtension("sys");` But I get a valid wxIcon object with or without that change.

Comment: @NewPagodi Thanks, yes I have modified my code. My second example only worked if called in ```::OnInit``` but I was putting my test code in the constructor instead. Obviously something happens between construction and ```OnInit``` calls. I was also foolishly using ```wxBITMAP_TYPE_ICON``` (which doesn't work) instead of ```wxBITMAP_TYPE_ICO``` (which does work). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you specify type `wxBITMAP_TYPE_ICO`.

Comment: ```wxIcon::LoadFile``` fails for me with that. It  cannot find a handler for wxBITMAP_TYPE_ICON. The fallback within that function to attempt to load with wxBitmap/wxImage fails too. I load all image handlers with ::wxInitAllImageHandlers() but no joy. Any other tips would be welcomed, thanks again.

Comment: I was foolishly using ```wxBITMAP_TYPE_ICON``` instead of ```wxBITMAP_TYPE_ICO```. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `LoadFile()` must specify the icon resource ID when using `wxBITMAP_TYPE_ICO` (which is indeed what you need to use when loading icons from files, and not resources of the current module), i.e. you're also missing the `;N` part at the end, where `N` is the value returned by `wxFileTypeInfo::GetIconIndex()`.

But to avoid dealing with this explicitly, you should just use `wxFileType::GetIcon()` and construct `wxIcon` from the `wxIconLocation` filled in by it.

For example, this:

```
diff --git a/samples/minimal/minimal.cpp b/samples/minimal/minimal.cpp
index 0d91f7fc75..3623aacc56 100644
--- a/samples/minimal/minimal.cpp
+++ b/samples/minimal/minimal.cpp
@@ -123,6 +123,12 @@ bool MyApp::OnInit()
     if ( !wxApp::OnInit() )
         return false;

+    wxIcon icon(wxIconLocation(R"(c:\Windows\system32\imageres.dll)", -67));
+    if ( icon.IsOk() )
+    {
+        wxLogMessage("Loaded icon of size %d*%d", icon.GetWidth(), icon.GetHeight());
+    }
+
     // create the main application window
     MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame("Minimal wxWidgets App");
```

shows the expected message about loading the icon of size 32 by 32.

Comment: Thanks - the call to LoadFile inside wxIcon's constructor when passed an wxIconLocation also fails (no handler I think). I have not modified the default wxWidgets setup for building on Windows; are there any specific options that are required for appropriate image handlers?

Comment: Not sure what goes wrong for you. The handlers used by `wxIcon` and `wxBitmap` are _not_ `wxImage` handlers and don't need to be initialized, they're always built in and forward to the native `::ExtractIcon()` function. And it definitely works for me, see the updated example.

Comment: OK! This works! Note that it works in MyApp::OnInit and *not* the constructor, so something else must have occurred between. Also, ```wxBITMAP_TYPE_ICO``` works but ```wxBITMAP_TYPE_ICON``` (notice the *N*) does not. Thanks!

Comment: The library is not initialized yet when `wxApp` object is constructed, you can't do anything non-trivial in it, which is why `OnInit()` exists (see also `OnExit()`).

Comment: Thanks - I don't normally do anything in the constructor at all of course, but was only doing it for this test code. Thanks again.